# Get sum value of each table

Tags: jquery

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table>
 <tr>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>5</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I have multiple... well, for convenience sake, let's just say that I have 2 tables like the code above. I want to append a new column for each table, and the new column would have the sum of their respective table's pre-appended columns.

so the first table would print out 3, while the second one print out 12.

How can I do it using jquery?

---

(here's an image for easier understanding)

[image]

Comment: You can just iterate through each of this rows \ tables, get its text content, convert it to number and calculate the sum, and then append a new DOM element with text content of its sum.

Comment: you want to append a column (as you say in the question) or a row (as you say in the picture)?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to iterate through all the tables, then iterate through all it's rows and sum each value inside their data. You can't use `.val()` for td elements, but you can fetch it's value using `.text()`.

```
// Observation, it would be best if you add a class to the tables you are modifying.
function addSum() {
    var tables = $('table');
    $.each(tables, function() {
        var rows = $(this).children('tr');
        var sum = 0;
        $.each(rows, function(){
           sum += parseInt($(this).find('td').text(), 10);
        });
        $(this).append('<tr><td>'+sum+'</td></tr>');
    })
}
```

Next time, remember to add some code, otherwise we would be doing all the code for you.